# Basic question about assigning items to groups

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are 9 items, which are assigned to three groups. The first group may contain 2 items, the second 3, and the last one 4. In how many different ways the items may be assigned to the groups?

So I am dealing with combinations here. I know that there are $9\choose 2$ ways of picking two objects to a set, $9\choose 3$ ways of picking three objects to a set, and $9\choose 4$ ways of picking four objects to a set.

So, is the correct answer the product of those?

Comment: Applying your method to a similar but simpler situation, it looks like you would compute there are $\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}=27$ ways to assign $3$ items to three groups of one item each. However, you know there are actually only $3!=6$ possible assignments. Studying this discrepancy might suggest a correct solution method.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the product of:

${9}\choose{2}$${7}\choose{3}$${4}\choose{4}$

since after having filled the first group with 2 items, there are only 7 left to fill the second group, etc.

Note that ${9}\choose{4}$${5}\choose{3}$${2}\choose{2}$ leads to the same number ($1260$), so does ${9}\choose{4}$${5}\choose{2}$${3}\choose{3}$.